# Вызов JS функции из echo PHP

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть скрипт, в нём происходит авторизация. При неправильном вводе пароля, мне через JS функцию вызывает код

```
if ($pass_md5 != $select_passw)
{
    echo "<script>fadeEffect.init('error', 1);</script>";
}
```

Но он не работает. Почему?

Comment: может есть где вживую глянуть?

Comment: спасибо, я уже решил проблему. Возможно это был кривой скрипт, но после перехода на jQuery fade.In, всё стало отлично работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если в других местах код правельный, то следует указать тип:
    <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: не работает, всё равно

Comment: может быть из-за экранирования? Но я и так и сяк пытался. Никак.

Comment: ну если проблема не в этом, то попытайся таким образом вывести алерт, а дальше смотри тип fadeEffect и init в частности

Comment: alert в echo работает

Comment: тогда проблема 100% в самом объекте fadeEffect, ему либо по дому какого-то элемента не хватает, либо проблема в нём самом

Comment: в html виде всё работает

Answer (score 0):

1. Миллион причин.
2. Читайте первое.

Вывод до создания объекта `fadeEffect`, смотрите консоль ошибок.

Comment: сделал 3 echo.
Сначала добавил скрипт fading.js (функция)
Затем вывел <div> с сообщением
Затем вывел функцию с выполнением функции.
Изначально консоль ругалась на: Cannot read property. Но после добавления ещё двух строчек (сообщение и саму функцию), консоль исправно молчит. P.S. Все скрипты в чистом html, работают на 5!

Comment: строка с сообщением у меня и так была, но ниже кодом в теле авторизации